# forming a path from matrix adjacency

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

if i have a node adjacency each number represent node id

```
                    A  = [ 3 7;
                           4 7;
                           6 9;
                           3 10;
                           4 10;
                           7 10]
```

how can i get the result which suppose to form a pathway

```
                          [3 7 10 4]
                          [4 7 10 3]
                          [6 9 0 0]
                          [3 10 4 7]
                          [4 10 3 7]
                          [7 10 4 7]
```

from matrix A the first row with value 3 will lead to value 7 and from 7 it search the matrix  A which lead to last row that connected 7 to the number 10. So from number 10 it can choose either value 3 or 4 as next number. i want the answer have no repeating number in one row but doesnt need to end with highest id number it will end if the next number is a repeated from previous . Hope i made myself clear as im a beginner in matlab. many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This belongs to the graph theory field. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there are several toolboxes that provide algrithms common when dealing with such problems:

- [Bioinformatics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/a1052308804.html#bqur9d7-1) [Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/biographobject.html) from MathWorks
- [Matgraph](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19218)
- [grTheory](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4266)
- [MatlabBGL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922)
- [gaimc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24134)

Answer (score 0):

Use breadth-first search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). You can either reject paths which are invalid for your criteria during the search or filter them out afterward.

You should clarify your question further. It is not entirely clear what you are asking for.